# Synchronize data between many threads

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm new to the synchronization topic and I couldn't find clear information anywhere about using `wait()`, `notify()`, and `notifyAll()` methods while trying to access to synchronized object. For exmaple if we have such code:

```
class X extends Thread {
    int x;

    public void methodX()
    {
       synchronized(this)
       {
           //some operations on x
       }
    }
}

class Y extends Thread {
    public void methodY(X x)
    { 
        int z = x.x;
    }
}
```

Should we call `wait()` in `methodY()` and `notify()` at the end of `methodX()`?
Otherwise we will not assign any value to `z` or the thread will wait without explicitly calling `wait()` until X unlocks?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Include a main()

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Since X.x is accessed by multiple threads, every access should simply be synchronized on the same object. Read the [Java tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), and Java Concurrency in Practice from Brian Goetz. Also read the javadoc of wait() and notify() to see what their purpose and usage is.

Comment: Some clarification please... is your requirement that `method`'s assignment of `z` should not occur until after `methodX` has executed?

Comment: John B, yes thats correct

Comment: Then forget what I said. You need some signalling between the threads. But use a higher level abstraction like a Semaphore rather than using wait() and notify(). They are too low-level and hard to use correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So give that you need `methodY` to wait until `methodX` has executed, one valid way of doing this is `wait` and `notify` or `notifyAll`. There are of course multiple other ways but that one is valid. Given that you may not even need the synchronized block.

```
void methodX(){
       // do your work here
       this.notifyAll();
}

void methodY(X x){
     x.wait();
     int x = X.x;
}
```

You might consider putting the blocking code in a `getX` method in `X` but the above will work IF (and this is a BIG IF) you can guarantee that `methodY` starts before `methodX` because otherwise `methodY` will miss the `notify` call.

All of the above said, I agree with `JB Nizet`, you might consider a more high-level mechanism such as a Semaphore / Mutex / etc. These ease the complexity. For example if you use a `CountDownLatch` and create it with a count of 1 your code will probably be more robust...

Consider:

```
class X{
    volatile int x;
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

    void methodX(){
        // do work here
        cdl.countDown();
    }

    int getX(){
        cdl.await();
        return x;
    }
}

class Y{
    void methodY(X x){
        int z = X.getX();
    }
}
```

The above will work every time without any ordering risks.